# Typescript generic union resolution order

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am trying to create an interface with string Union as the type parameter. It has two children, both are tied to the Union. The idea is that they are coordinated with each other through the type parameter.

Here's a simple repro:

```js
interface IOptions<TValue extends string> {
  values: {[key in TValue]: string};
  items: IItem<TValue>[];
}
interface IItem<TValue extends string> {
  value: TValue;
}

function printOptions<TValue extends string>(options: IOptions<TValue>) {
  console.log(options);
}

printOptions({
  values: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
  items: [
    { value: 'a'}
  ]
});
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsQDOAPACoBqcANgK4oQAekIAJgcgWFKAOYB8yAbwBQyZADcqtAgC5BAbQDWEAJ7JQycpIgBdWRy4huAXwDcItZAC2MtKiukKNCLznazRoaEixEKVHYhLBy1kBiZWdk4efmFRCSdZTSd3ISEYahAEHHxkTAMwLGzCYKdQxggWNn1ogApcbDxCWQwG-GIk2l4ASkFzBDbcSggAOkpcbjrWwi6UoTyvQsaCGtjxLRsBOFkAcjhtgBpkACMdo+2jffNgKxs5c1EBNYTkXfPzbSEjGaA

This code produces the following error:

```
Type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; }'.
```

My guess as to what happens is that typescript decides that `items` array will be the child that defines what the generic Union is, and then complains that `values` has unknown properties.

My question is, can I somehow make typescript use `values` as the "union definer" type? Or in some other way make it so that `values` can have keys that don't appear in `items`?

Comment: DO you want to forbid  any key from `values` in `items`?

Comment: Yes. `items` should only have keys that appear in `values`.

Comment: I made an update. please take a look on my answer

Answer (score 2):

You just need to infer each key and value of the argument.
COnsider this example:

```js
interface Option<Values, Items> {
  values: Values;
  items: Items;
}

type Item<Value extends PropertyKey> = { value: Value }

function printOptions<
  Value extends string,
  Values extends Record<Value, Value>,
  InferedItem extends Item<keyof Values>,
  Items extends InferedItem[]
>(options: Option<Values, Items>) {
}

printOptions({
  values: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
  items: [
    { value: 'a' }
  ]
});


printOptions({
  values: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
  items: [
    { value: 'c' } // error
  ]
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgDwBqcANgK4QDOANMgJKQC2FAfMgN4BQyyAbieRQBcyImUoBuLsmCMhdWZIC%20HDmACe6FPQgNC-FBAAekEABMKyAApRsmqOoDSENawC87XvuGjyyZRxhSEAQsXGR0KFAwDFCQCjwpHwNjCDMLCjBIkABzKkT9CyMTc2QAJQgEbChTPTEaJOY87loQGGgIU20GZCLUkq68AGtnbBgRAsapLsKUtLpW9s7GAG0AXQ5mAApbWLkYnHwk6nkdFgBKdg5-CKj93ApNzm4%20MTk2ZDhhAHI4L5oAI2%20-y%20fia0lkwmWUm47xe5G%20vz8UnWijO4iAA)

Treat it as a type destuction. If you want to infer each value, you should destructure it. In other words create the result type from the bottom to top.

1. First of all, you need to infer `key/value` of `values` proeprty:  `Value extends string`
2. Then, you need to infer whole `values` property: `Values extends Record<Value, Value>`
3. Same approach with items. You need to infer one item: `InferedItem extends Item<keyof Values>`
4. Then you can infer all items: `Items extends InferedItem[]`

If you are interested in `Type Inference on function arguments` you can take a look on my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

If you want to forbid using `values` keys in `items` array, you need to provida validation type helper. You can find more explanation and examples in my [article/blog](https://catchts.com/type-negation).

```js
interface Option<Values, Items> {
  values: Values;
  items: Items;
}

type Item<Value extends PropertyKey> = { value: Value }

type Check<
  Values extends Record<string, string>,
  Items extends Array<any>,
  Cache extends Array<any> = []
  > =
  Items extends []
  ? Cache
  : Items extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Head extends Item<infer Value>
  ? Value extends keyof Values
  ? Check<Values, Tail, [...Cache, Item<never>]>
  : Check<Values, Tail, [...Cache, Item<Value>]>
  : 1
  : Items;


function printOptions<
  Value extends string,
  ItemValue extends string,
  Values extends Record<Value, Value>,
  InferedItem extends Item<ItemValue>,
  Items extends InferedItem[],
  >(options: Option<Values, Check<Values, [...Items]>>) {
}


printOptions({
  values: { a: 'a', b: 'b' },
  items: [
    { value: 'c' }, // ok
    { value: 'a' }, // error
  ]
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgDwBqcANgK4QDOANMgJKQC2FAfMgN4BQyyAbieRQBcyImUoBuLsmCMhdWZIC%20HDmACe6FPQgNC-FBAAekEABMKyAApRsmqOoDSENawC87XvuGjyyZao0UAGEACwgEAGs8KR9KZCMTc2QAJXDsKFM8CjAoUABzGmzckDzmKiltJnjjCDMLAEEoKDg1PDgQF3LuIMQw6sSGppa2jrdkAG0AXSk3Ctl%202qSpqQB%20ZB6EMKlhSosExYtx0BhoZAAJCDhTGgA6O%20PTgBU4YGJp7jWLq4W6%20R08B5QET6ZirYFiH5JCLObAwcECMGhcJRWLUZDPV40cZ3G4bMI0Sp4EAQHjQZiTUHcYRIyJ6MRojHELE4vEQAmMOnkcmU5DCACM2z%20TEkKhgpBACCwuGQ6GKYAwUpAFGi3FikIsRXyXSFav2v01JW1qPVKTSGU5bPhEDKFRAJygEFMlRNhMqsRt3F2Lrt0EdlSm2uYAApbIq5AqcPhUTQaSj9GjsXddhTmABKdgcfwcWWgeWYSMUIOcbh8enCNjIODCADkcGrNAARjWG9W-NqZDo5OMpNwK6XyDWEK3FDQAPSj5DYCI9jz9iA1utt5Dj%20JNdJSaaKVMioA)

Validation algorithm: iterate through `items` tuple and check every `value` whether it extends any key from `values`. If yes - replace `value:char` with `value:never`, otherwise don't do anything with `item`.

`Check` returns validated `items` tuple which is used as a second argument for `Options`. Now, we ended up with a tuple, where each invalid `value` is replaved by `never`. SInce `never` is unrepresentable it is highlighted by TS compiler.

Comment: This seems to be solving this example. A bit of an issue is that if you use `Option` type outside of this function, it is no longer constrained. You can put anything into `Values` and anything into `Items`, and it will work. This function is the only place where their relation is constrained.

Comment: But your ideas gave me an idea towards a solution that seems to work for my use case. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through captain-yossarian's solution, I came up with this, which works better in my case.

```js
type IValuesLookup = {[key: string]: string};
type StringKeys<T> = keyof T extends string ? keyof T : never;

interface IOptions<TValues extends IValuesLookup, TItem extends IItem<StringKeys<TValues>>> {
  values: TValues;
  items: TItem[];
}
interface IItem<TValue extends string> {
  value: TValue;
}

function printOptions<TValues extends IValuesLookup, TItem extends IItem<StringKeys<TValues>>>(options: IOptions<TValues, TItem>) {
  console.log(options);
}

printOptions({
  values: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
  items: [
    { value: 'a'}
  ]
});
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgagQwDYFcIGcAyB7bBrFMKAXigG8BtPCEALinWACcBLAOwHMBdex1zgL4BuAFChIUAMrN2HANI10AHgAqAPhJRqIbADMoKqBAAewCGwAm6BjM5QA-Fpp6DUemwgA3CE1Ej2Zky6CADG0DAA8mDALNhsyiqIqBhGpuZWsEloWLgEYAA0BjBmALapZpbWMMUQJUrS-PKKqlkYau3kIlBQnsjZ9Il9GKLdLKXoAzUlFFyiAv5sgcFhsFMtQ+Xp1nyyGmRdPUMDrXMiIroobCExcVBg-MBRN-HrydYmFRnwQzn4hIUqKabSqrUr1WxNEAJVrodpqAAU2GisXi9EiyLi0J+AKmagAlJ1uiFMdgkBAAHRIbAcREY+J404ie4BJ4o9Dw-bdXpvehkBD0ADkCAFhQARoLRQKBPkDmNahMoBQDt0yIdkoLhfNulwRAIGUA